# WCF и RecordSet

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Мне нужно сделать, что бы служба передавала клиенту RecordSet MSSQL и на основании этого заполнялась клиентская форма.

Подскажите, может ли возвращать такой тип данных служба, если нет, то как это обойти и вообще является ли это хорошей практикой?

Comment: Что значит RecordSet MSSQL? RecordSet это из [ADO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms681510(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Да, вы правы. Я выбрал ,немного, некорректную формулировку...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передается всё, что сериализуется. Возвращай DataSet или DataTable